# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MapTypeId')

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm using the [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#web) package in a Flutter Web app but when I run the app, the widget containing my GoogleMaps component is red and I get the following error in my console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MapTypeId')
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To use the google_maps_flutter package on web, you need to perform the setup steps listed in the [google_maps_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web) package. Mainly, this means adding the following script to web/index.html:

```
<head>

  <!-- // Other stuff -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
</head>
```